# Create Restful API web service for android app

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I have created Login page in asp.net with MySQL and that web application published on IIS. I want to access that username and password using Web service in my android app. how to create web service for that and how to access it my app please help me.

Comment: Sorry didn't get your point

Comment: yes i will go through the link

Comment: yes i have also go through that link that's why i am saying that.

Comment: if you have not solution don't give and thanks for your response. and i have also edited my question

Answer (score 0):

WEB Api is a platform to create Restful services which can easily consumed by your android app, web application etc. Refer this link [Create Restful services](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d9083/how-to-create-web-api-in-asp-net-mvc/)